# Non quadratic way to perform dictionary assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

say I have the following data (this is a mock example as my original dataset contains more than 3 Million observations):

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [[2, [4], None], [4, [9,18,6], None], [6, [], 9],[7, [2], None],[9, [4], 7],[14, [18,6], 3],[18, [7], 1]]
  
# Create the mock pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['docdb', 'cited_docdb','fronteer'])

import math
df.replace(' NaN', np.NaN)
df['distance'] = np.where((df['fronteer'] >0), 0, math.inf)
```

what I need to do is basically this operation (which basically reverts the data):

```
keys= [k for k in df.explode('cited_docdb')['cited_docdb'].unique()]
values=[df.explode('cited_docdb').loc[df.explode('cited_docdb')['cited_docdb']== j, 'docdb'].to_list() for j in prova.keys()]

inverting_db = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

in a non-quadratic way (as you can see, "values" has a quadratic complexity).
I think the best option might be to populate the inverting_db dictionary with a for loop somehow but did not manage to figure out a way. Could you please help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, what is `prova`? You are using the variable in your list comprehension.

Comment: Oh prova is a dictionary containing some docdb